# Redirect, but preserve part of URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

its possible create a redirect, replace only part in the URL?
another part preserve...

in this case ONLY `listing` to `business`

EXAMPLE:

```
www.example.com/listing/new-york
www.example.com/listing/boston
www.example.com/listing/etc...
```

to

```
www.example.com/business/new-york
www.example.com/business/boston
www.example.com/business/etc...
```

thank you for tips :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly easy to do with mod_rewrite. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2) if you need help enabling that.

Then add the following to your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^listing/(.*)$ business/$1 [R,L]
```

Change the `[R]` flag to `[R=301]` after testing the redirect works as expected to turn the redirect into a permanent redirect.